# Post method wont add results to the table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, pug

Whenever I try to push user into my table it doesn't do anything at all. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
.wrapper.d-flex.flex-column
    br
    input#fname(type='text', name='text' placeholder="name" v-model="name")
    br
    br
    input#lname(type='email', name='email' placeholder="email" v-model="email")
    br
    input#lname(type='phone', name='phone' placeholder="phone" v-model="phone")
    br
    input(type='submit', value='Submit' @click="addUser()")
```

```
data() {
   return  {
     users: [],
     name: '',
     email: '',
     phone: ''
   }
```

```
adduser() {
      axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/', {
        name: this.name,
        email: this.email,
        phone: this.phone
      }).then((response) => {
        this.users.push(response.data);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

In `then` function `this` keyword refers to different object. Because of that you need to store `this` value before post method. You can try this function:

```
adduser() {
  var that = this;
  axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/', {
    name: this.name,
    email: this.email,
    phone: this.phone
  }).then((response) => {
    that.users.push(response.data);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
},
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/g-kt-rk-burak-k-se/pen/mdPmjaV According to this pen your code works well. Maybe you have some errors on your table or axios import. Can you check your table props. Are they matching with response props?

Comment: get method works perfectly on my table. It grabs the data. `tr(v-for="user in users")
          td {{ user.name }}
          td {{ user.email }}
          td {{ user.phone }}` I honestly have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: `[Vue warn]: Extraneous non-props attributes (data-v-41458b80) were passed to component but could not be automatically inherited because component renders fragment or text root nodes. ` This is in my console.